# import multiple excel files to database in pentaho 6

Tags: excel, import, pentaho

I want to import multiple excel files to my db follow a loop. For example,  I put all excel files in a for and each excel file import to my db.
Because when I try to import all files in forder which I has maximum of 2 files to import. Three files shows errors related to ram.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Get file names** step as an input to get all the excel files.

You feed the information of the Get file names to the **Microsoft excel input** step, this step has a check to accept filenames from previous step.

To make this work all excel files must have the same structure, if they have different structure, you'll have to inject metadata with the differences in each file, and you'll have to build a logic in previous transformations to determine the metadata to inject.

Comment: When I create a new job that has same steps. it is fine to run data. Many thanks.